# Group Policy Printer hangup at user logon

Tags: windows, printing, printers, group-policy, gpo

So we are occasionally having hang ups at logon with Applying Group Policy printers on the screen after the user has entered username and password credentials.

I setup logging for this so I could analyse when this was happening to try and determine a cause.

It has happened this morning with a 5 minute hang up on the below part.

"2024-02-06 10:24:14.550 [pid=0xe20,tid=0x1810] Set user security context.

2024-02-06 10:29:00.047 [pid=0xe20,tid=0x1810] Set system security context."

Does anybody have any ideas of where to go next with investigating this? Why would a PC take 5 mins to "set the user context"?